# Why electron positron pair move oppositely inspite of attraction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gamma-rays, pair-production

In pair production the two antiparticles always move in opposite direction I wonder why is that so though I know it is to conserve energy but the basic principle unlike charged particle attract should we dump it in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The principle is not being dumped. The thing that you are missing is the difference between acceleration and velocity.

In pair production, the particles have velocities in opposite directions. However they attract each other, both of them will decelerate.

Thing is it as throwing a ball upwards. The ball is attracted by the earth and yet you can throw it against the attraction. The particles are similarly thrown away.

Comment: but mostly there is a confusion even in cases when think of situation we have an electron and we accelerate it toward hydrogn cation thats a proton then instead of going to it and get clung to it electron start revolving round it please clear.Never the less answer is good one'

Comment: It can be proved that beyond a certain velocity that the electron will not hit the nucleus if it isn't exactly in line with the nucleus.

Comment: And I think that rather than you asking more questions, you should read a little bit about the question that you are asking. Cause every doubt you have is very basic physics. And this site has strict policies, which will get your question deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because of momentum conservation.

Comment: then should e dump the rule that like charges attract a more common known rule Simply!